# Calling Identity Server Token EndPoint

Tags: javascript, c#, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I want to call the [Token Endpoint](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/endpoints/token.html) of IdentityServer 4 from my React App (running on `http://localhost:3000`). So in some login method I am doing:

```
login = () => {
    const userdata = {
      username: 'admin',
      password: 'admin',
    };
    const dataForBody = `${'client_id=js&'}${'grant_type=password&' +
        'username='}${encodeURI(userdata.username)}&` +
        `password=${encodeURI(userdata.password)}&` +
        `scope=${encodeURI('api1')}`;

    const messageHeaders = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    };

    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'http://localhost:5000/connect/token',
      headers: messageHeaders,
      data: dataForBody,
    })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      });
  }
```

Now I am getting the following response:

```
{"error":"unauthorized_client"}
```

My IdSrv set up is something like the js application sample.

**config.cs**

```
namespace QuickstartIdentityServer
{
    public class Config
    {
        // scopes define the API resources in your system
        public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
        {
            return new List<ApiResource>
            {
                new ApiResource("api1", "My API")
            };
        }

        // client want to access resources (aka scopes)
        public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
        {
            return new List<Client>
            {
                 new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "js",
                    ClientName = "JavaScript Client",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,

                    RedirectUris =           { "http://localhost:3000/login" },
                    AllowedCorsOrigins =     { "http://localhost:3000" },

                    AllowedScopes =
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        "api1"
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        public static List<TestUser> GetUsers()
        {

            return new List<TestUser> {
                new TestUser {
                    SubjectId = "1", Username = "admin", Password = "admin"
                },
             };

        }

    }
}
```

**startup.cs**

```
namespace QuickstartIdentityServer
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // configure identity server with in-memory stores, keys, clients and scopes
            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddTemporarySigningCredential()
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
                .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers());
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Debug);
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            app.UseIdentityServer();
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the client definition:

```
AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
```

is not correct. We have to use instead:

```
AllowedGrantTypes = ResourceOwnerPassword
```

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem that jumps out is that you are attempting to authenticate with the token service by passing the username and password as URL parameters.  The client's username and password should be passed in using a standard basic authorization header:

```
Authorization: Basic Base64Encode(myusername:mypassword)
```

Which for this example would end up looking like this:

```
Authorization: Basic bXl1c2VybmFtZTpteXBhc3N3b3Jk
```

Comment: Hello thank you for the response. Now I added `Authorization: Basic $btoa('admin:admin')` removed the username and password from the body, and now it says me: `invalid_client`

Comment: I would take a look at the actual request being generated by using Chrome developer tools (Network tab) or something like Postman.  Make sure your form parameters are getting encoded as you expect them to.  One problem there could result in the whole set of parameters getting thrown off.